# Why doesn't the socket close on the other side of the socket? (close_wait)?

Tags: c#, c++, c, sockets

I have an issue with sockets. I'm creating a socket between my computer and my phone to send messages. When I close the server or the client it sends a FIN packet and it stays in the FIN_WAIT2 state for like a minute. However, the other side get stuck in the CLOSE_WAIT state, apparently incapable of closing the socket. I reckon that sockets should be closed instantly, so maybe I should somehow implement a code in the client that closes the socket when the server wants to close it and vice versa. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close both ends of a socket channel.

If the server closes a connection to a client, the client needs to close the connection on the client-end, for the last `FIN` packet to be transmitted (from client to server). This will trigger the last state transition in the [TCP state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg).

Comment: thank you, but I don't know how to implement the code to close the connection on the client. When I close the server, it automatically closes the socket on its side. Should I test some condition or catch some exception on the client side and close the socket if something goes wrong? Would it be the way to implement this?

Comment: @cracq When the remote end of a socket is closed, the local end becomes readable, and a subsequent read operation will return with a zero length read. This means the socket has been closed nicely from the remote end and that you should close your end as well.

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT means that the peer has sent a FIN and TCP is waiting for the local application to close the socket. See RFC 793. It doesn't happen automatically.